# Creating a sequence of has_many: :through objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am building an application that allows users to create a custom diet for their dogs for a given number of days.  Users should be able to pick the order of the diet, i.e. dogbone first, steak next, then kibble, etc.  So far I have this:

`class Dog < ...
  has_many :regimes
  has_many meals, through: :regimes
end`

`class Regime < ...
  belongs_to :dog
  belongs_to :meal
end`

So how do I define a particular sequence for the regime?  I figure this feature will reside in the `Regime` class but I'm not sure how to proceed.  Any input much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to use conditions in your association (or [customize the query](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Customizing+the+query)), as follows:

```
#app/models/dog.rb
Class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :regimes, -> { order :meal_order }
end
```

Comment: Thanks Rich.  What I'm struggling with is how to set `:meal_order` in my Regime#new form.  Right now I'm iterating over the meals and have a select dropdown for each meal.  A Regime will have many `assigned_meals` which belong to Meal.  Is this a reasonable approach?